# OAuth 2.0 with DotNetOpenAuth for .NET not work with google account

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth, google-authenticator

I Try to use OAuth 2.0 for google authorize with DotNetOpenAuth library for .NET, the code works on Facebook, but with google when I request callback to google endpoint, after user select a google account, the response only return a Bad Request (status code 400)

My code is like

```
public class GoogleClient : WebServerClient
{
    private static readonly AuthorizationServerDescription GoogleDescription = new AuthorizationServerDescription
    {
        TokenEndpoint = new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"),
        AuthorizationEndpoint = new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"), 
        ProtocolVersion = ProtocolVersion.V20            
    };

    public GoogleClient() : base(GoogleDescription) { }
}
```

Use

```
GoogleClient client = new GoogleClient
{
    ClientIdentifier = ConfigurationHelper.GoogleAppId,
    ClientCredentialApplicator = ClientCredentialApplicator.PostParameter(ConfigurationHelper.GoogleAppSecret)
};

client.ProcessUserAuthorization();
```

Answer (score 0):

We are having the same problem. I have noticed that the scope parameter is included within the redirect_uri parameter in the http post body request (for some strange reason, it is not encoded correctly)
I think it is time to move to another lib.